# how to set static names for lxc-veth-devices on the host?

Tags: networking, lxc

lxc is creating a new veth-device on the host for a container, each time, the respective container (re)starts. the name of the veth-device consits of "veth" and some random string.
I cannot really see an advantage in that behaviour, but if there is one, i would also like to know.

But the main question is: How can you set a static veth-device name for a container?

I would like veth-device-names to be static because e.g. monitoring a containers traffic would be more convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Man page](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/manpages/man5/lxc.container.conf.5.html):

> **NETWORK**
>
> ......
>
> **veth**: .....
>   By default, lxc chooses a name for the network device belonging to the outside of the container, but if you wish to handle this name yourselves, you can tell lxc to set a specific name with the lxc.network.veth.pair option (except for unprivileged containers where this option is ignored for security reasons).

You should use it as follows:

```
lxc.network.veth.pair = vethvm1
```

You can find many useful examples of container networking [on the Debian Wiki LXC manpage](https://wiki.debian.org/LXC).

Comment: nowadays it's `lxc.net.0.veth.pair = vethvm1`